# My LINQ Query seems to recognise the entries that match the condition, but these entries are not returned to the variable?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

Here is my LINQ query:

```
var paragraphs = Context.Paragraphs.Where(o => text.Contains(o.PlainText.Trim()));
```

When using software such as OzCode, I am able to see that the LINQ query does match the entries in the DbSet, however, during debugging when stepping over, the 'paragraps' var does not contain the entries.

Am I writing the query incorrectly?

Thanks!

Note: After trying to enumerate with ToList(), the same results are seen:

[image]

Comment: `Queryable.Where` has deferred execution. The query is only executed when it is enumerated.

Comment: My bet on IEnumerable. Where does not query till it need to. Add a `ToList()` for example to force the execution

Comment: After trying to enumerate with ToList(), the same results are seen.

Comment: @HarryStout Could you please show an entry that is present in OzCode and not present when the query is executed? Maybe you want to track the statement executed with an sql profiler and compare the query you expect with the query executed.

Comment: @Dominik, I have edited the post with a picture where you should be able to see the LINQ analysis from OzCode containing the two entries that are filtered in the Where() clause. When executing this line of code, the debugger shows no entries for the paragraph variable (Count = 0).

Comment: @HarryStout I know this sounds crazy but can you let the debugger pass this line, set the breakpoint to where `workIds` is initialized and then straight look into the paragraphs variable? Do not use OzCode before looking into the variable! Maybe OzCode iterates some `IEnumerable` whose pointer is then set to the end.

Comment: Hi @Dominik, I'm afraid that hasn't changed anything...

Comment: @HarryStout Then please try to sniff the SQL going on with a sqlprofiler to try and see what's going on on the db. My current guess is, that ozcode loads all Paragraphs from the db and then does the contains inmemory while EF generates a SQL statement that for some reason does not match the entries.

Comment: Hi @Dominik, I think you may be correct. I found the SQL being executed by EF contains the query for the Where() clause, and OzCode only ever executes SQL to retrieve the full list of Paragraphs so it must be enumerating the Where() clause in memory!

Comment: Maybe you need `o.PlainText.Contains(text.Trim())`?

Comment: @HarryStout alright, that's a good starter then. Now you must figure why the query does not match your expected entries. Without the select, a sample entry and the database system (oracle, mssql, postgres...) we won't be able to assist you any further